# continue show popup chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, show-hide

I try to make a chrome extension. For this project I need to have a function that when I activate my popup by clicking on a icon it will not close when I am by instant select a text in a webpage. Normally the popup will hide automatically.

I there a way to block the auto hide function in the google chrome extension.

Thank you,

Wouter

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do that in Chrome by design. If you want something to show / hide, please use a [Page Action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html) instead of a [Browser Action](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/browserAction.html).

For the page action, you can [show](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#method-show) and [hide](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/pageAction.html#method-hide) the page popup.

Comment: doesn't show just show the icon (as opposed to showing the popup window)?

Comment: You cannot programmatically show/hide the browser action icon, this is by design.